# How to speed up the restlet client to get response?

Tags: performance, rest, client, restlet

I use restlet client to send rest request to the server.

```
public class RestHandler {
    protected ClientResource resource       = null;
    protected Client         client         = null;

    public void connect(final String address,
                       final Protocol protocol){
        final Context context = new Context();
        if (client == null) {
            logger.info("Create Client.");
            client = new Client(context, protocol);
        }
        resource = new ClientResource(context, new Reference(protocol, address));
        resource.setNext(client);
        resource.setEntityBuffering(true);
    }
}
```

In its child class, use resource.get()/post/put/delete to send rest request.

I found the response come back so slow at the first time(5-10s).

And then it go faster in the next few requests.

But after waiting about 10min I send the request again, it become slow again.

Is there any way to make the response come back faster?

Comment: Are you sure that Restlets are the problem here?

Comment: It's much faster to use Firefox browser to send rest request. So I think there maybe some way to speed up restlet client

Comment: A broswer dependency sounds a lot like a JavaScript AJAX problem rather than something with the server side and Restlets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use another client connector. It can be the cause of your problem, especially if you use the default one. Notice that the default one should be used for development only.

This page gives you all the available client connectors: http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/core/base/connectors.

Regarding client connectors, you can configure properties to tune them. To use a client connector, simply put the corresponding Restlet extension within your classpath. Perhaps can you make a try with the extension `org.restlet.ext.httpclient`.

This answer could help you regarding connector configuration and properties: [Restlet HTTP Connection Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417669/restlet-http-connection-pool/28438070#28438070).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks very much. I add the org.restlet.ext.httpclient.jar to classpath.
But there's no HttpClient Class, only have the HttpClientHelper.
How to use it to create the apach http client?

Comment: You're welcome! In fact, there is no impact on the code you used. The client connector is registered under the hood by Restlet itself. If you want to be sure that it's the case, simply have a look at the client connector list from `Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients()`. You will see the one from the extension `org.restlet.ext.httpclient`. If you want to pass parameters to configure it, simply use the context used as parameter during client creation. Hope it helps you.